# Compilation error building intero

Tags: haskell-stack, intero

I cannot use emacs on a new stack project because intero fails to build.

1. I've just installed stack 1.6.3 on ubuntu 16.04
2. I created a new (lts-10.2) stack project ('play') using: `stack new play`
3. When I try to open the source files in emacs it fails to build intero

   ```
   Intero is not installed in the Stack environment.

   Installing intero-0.1.24 automatically ...

   intero-0.1.24: configure
   intero-0.1.24: build

   --  While building custom Setup.hs for package intero-0.1.24 using:
   /home/wmorgan/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_2.0.1.0_ghc-8.2.2 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0 build --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
   Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
   Logs have been written to: /home/wmorgan/haskell/play/.stack-work/logs/intero-0.1.24.log
   Configuring intero-0.1.24...
   Preprocessing executable 'intero' for intero-0.1.24..
   Building executable 'intero' for intero-0.1.24..
   [1 of 8] Compiling GhciTypes        ( src/GhciTypes.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/intero/intero-tmp/GhciTypes.o )
   [2 of 8] Compiling GhciMonad        ( src/GhciMonad.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/intero/intero-tmp/GhciMonad.o )
   [3 of 8] Compiling GhciTags         ( src/GhciTags.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/intero/intero-tmp/GhciTags.o )
   [4 of 8] Compiling GhciInfo         ( src/GhciInfo.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/intero/intero-tmp/GhciInfo.o )
   [5 of 8] Compiling GhciFind         ( src/GhciFind.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/intero/intero-tmp/GhciFind.o )
   [6 of 8] Compiling Paths_intero     ( .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/intero/autogen/Paths_intero.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/intero/intero-tmp/Paths_intero.o )
   [7 of 8] Compiling InteractiveUI    ( src/InteractiveUI.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/intero/intero-tmp/InteractiveUI.o )
   [8 of 8] Compiling Main             ( src/Main.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/intero/intero-tmp/Main.o )
   Linking .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/intero/intero ...
   /usr/bin/ld.gold: error: cannot find -ltinfo
   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
   `gcc' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)
   Could not install Intero!
   ```

(I've also tried building intero from the command-line with the same results.)

Edit: if I edit stack.yaml (in my project) to use lts-9.5 then intero builds OK - so this problem seems to be lts-10.2 specific.

Any ideas about how to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install libncurses-dev`

I found this information via this search https://github.com/commercialhaskell/intero/search?q=-ltinfo&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93 leading to https://github.com/commercialhaskell/intero/issues/456

Comment: Correction - what I actually did was follow the suggestion in the link you provide:  sudo apt-get install libtinfo-dev

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this recently when installing `intero` for an `lts-11.8` project on Kubuntu 18.04. The problem is the system is missing the `tinfo` library. The following command fixed the issue for me.

```
sudo apt-get install libtinfo-dev
```